# Show updated record without refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 page.
When double click row data in first page will be go to second page.
second page is for update purpose.
when successful update in second page and i want back to first page, the data show not updated in first page but when refresh the data will show updated record.

How can i get the updated record show in first page without click refresh?

below is first page aspx code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr style="cursor: hand;" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#E6F0FF'"
            onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#FFFFFF'"
            onclick="javascript:window.location.href='V_Updated.aspx?mail=<%#Eval("mail") %>'">

            <td class="line_table_td" style="text-align: center;"><%#Eval(" mail    ")%>&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="line_table_td" style="text-align: center;"><%#Eval(" remarks     ")%>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

second page aspx button back code:

```
<td class="btn_bg" onclick = "history.back();">Back</td>
```

Comment: Please post your question clearly.

Comment: Please learn how to format on stackoverflow. There is help when you're writing, and even a preview so you can see that your question currently makes no sense

Comment: unfortunately some browsers (apple) will not refresh the page when you click back no matter what you do.

Answer (score 1):

Better to use AJAX for updating data, if it is suitable for your project. This way you do not have to use two different pages.

http://www.webblogsforyou.com/ajax-introduction-how-to-use-ajax-in-asp-net-with-example/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't go back using the browser history (e.g. using `history.back()`). Different browsers handle caching differently, so it's difficult to control if your page would get refreshed. Provide a proper link to the previous page instead.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put a link in second page like below :

```
<a href="firstpage.aspx" > Back </a>
```